# Spring - websockets - sending files to the server

Tags: java, stomp, spring-websocket

According to the tickets at [Is it possible to send binary data with STOMP over WebSockets using Spring-WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213819/is-it-possible-to-send-binary-data-with-stomp-over-websockets-using-spring-webso) 's answer it should be possible to send and receive files using spring-websockets.

Currently I'm converting the file to an ArrayBuffer and then sending it:

```
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
                var file = fileInput.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                stompClient.send("/app/requests." + channelId + ".files", {}, reader.result);
            });
```

However as far as I can tell the controller doesn't receive the Bytearray in the messages payload.

```
@MessageMapping("requests.{channelId}.files")
    public void receiveFile(@DestinationVariable String channelId, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
```

Could anyone please post a working example on how this should be done properly?
Thank you

Comment: According to that answer you should try your use-case with the latest SF 4.1.5 version.